# How to auto-run Google Apps Script on my shared file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet and share for my friends. I create some convenient menus on it by google apps script. But my friends shared sheet do not know how to run or use google apps script. Can the script auto-run when I open my sheet, and my friends too?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, definitely possible.

You would have to create an installable trigger.

```
function scriptSetup() {
  createStartupFunction();
}
 
function createStartupFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onOpen')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onOpen()
    .create();
}

function onOpen(e) {
  //your stuff here
}
```

This way, the scriptSetup() is located on the first line so when copying a spreadsheet I would ask the other party who wants to use Sheets to click on Extensions > Apps Script > Run.

You can read more about [installable spreadsheet triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) and [how to manage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) them.

Comment: A slight improvement tot his would be to create a menu item or a button and ask them to press that instead of going to script editor.

Comment: I'm answering based on his question of autorun scripts after a spreadsheet has been copied, not doing a full code. If he has shared his code I would format it accordingly.

Comment: The way this is structure is so that on the event you create other functions using things like onEdit, onOpen, onFormSubmit,etc you would be able to include that portion into the scriptSetup as code based installable triggers that you can document to tell people to run once.